# are parameters with square brackets treated differently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

Is there something special about params with a syntax like this:

```
model[column]=value
```

i.e.

```
...?product[name]=grand&product[type]=chair
```

Are they treated any differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Other than being arranged into a hash called `params` like so:

```
{:product => {:name => 'grand', :type => 'chair'} }
```

You could then access these in your controller like this:

```
params[:product]        # would return {:name => 'grand', :type => 'chair'}
params[:product][:name] # would return 'grand'
```

You might use this to create a `product`:

```
@product = Product.new(params[:product])
```